# MongoDB equivalent of this SQL query

Tags: mongodb

I was wondering how to run equivalent of the following SQL query in MongoDB.

```
// 1 = current user ID

SELECT p.id, p.firstName, p.lastName from friendships f
JOIN person p ON p.id = f.requester
WHERE f.requestee = 1
UNION
SELECT p.id, p.firstName, p.lastName
from friendships f
JOIN person p ON p.id = f.requestee
WHERE f.requester = 1
```

friendships table

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╗
║ requester       requestee       type ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╣
║ userA           userC            1   ║
║ userB           userA            1   ║
║ userC           userD            1   ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Let's say I am `userA` my friends are according to the table above `userB` and `userC`, thus I need those two users to be returned.

MongoDB friendship document (collection friendships)

```
{
    requester: userID
    requestee: otherUserID
    type: // type of relationship (accepted, declined, blocked, etc.)
    time: // timestamp
}
```

MongoDB user document (collection users)

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('random')
    firstName: 'Someone',
    lastName: 'Random'
}
```

Desired result: All friends of current user and their user details.

```
[
    {
        firstName: 'John'
        lastName: 'Doe'
        time: // timestamp from friendship document
    },
    {
        firstName: 'Jane'
        lastName: 'Doe'
        time: // timestamp from friendship document
    },
    {
        firstName: 'James'
        lastName: 'Doe'
        time: // timestamp from friendship document
    }
]
```

Thank you very much in advance for all help.

Comment: How does your mongoDB schema look like? What collections are there?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please take the time to learn [ask]. You'll need to show some effort from your part if you want help. Thanks.

Comment: Step 1: Simplify the current SQL query. No need to UNION...

Comment: @YuvrajJaiswal I just updated the question.

Comment: Post some sample data @Sebastian

Comment: Hi @Krishna, just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer based on the information available in the questions. You might need to make changes as needed. Any improvements are appreciated.

```
db.friendship.aggregate([
{ 
      $lookup:{  
         from:"person",
         as: "p1",
         localField: "personid1",
         foreignField: "personid",
      }
    },
    { 
      $lookup:{  
         from:"person",
         as: "p2",
         localField: "personid2",
         foreignField: "personid",
      }
    },
    {
        $match:{ $or: [{personid1:"1"},{personid2:"1"}]}
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot:{ newRoot: {
            "persons" : { $setUnion : [ "$p1" , "$p2" ]}
        }
        }
    },{
        $unwind:{  path: "$persons"}
    },
    {
        $group:{ _id: {personid:"$persons.personid", firstname:"$persons.firstname", lastname:"$persons.lastname"} }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot:{ newRoot: {
            "personid" : "$_id.personid",
            "firstname" : "$_id.firstname",
            "lastname" : "$_id.lastname"
        }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Comment: It works like a charm, however there is one more thing, is it possible to exclude current user? It returns array of friends including the current user among them.

Comment: post some data for friendship and person collection

Comment: Those are in the question. It returns "Desired result" as described in question, but this result contains also the current user. It returns array of all your friends including you. And I need it to only return your friends.

Comment: If I am being honest. Your sql and the collections you posted doesnt match. I wrote the mongo query analogous to the sql query you had. I need exact information to help more. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is personA your current userID? if so why your sql query joining on 2 fields on person?